# How to replace the Sum with Total in List or Library setting in Sharepoint

Tags: 2013, list

I am working on SharePoint list using Totals feature under list view setteing which includes count, sum, average etc. Is it possible to change the sum text to Total.

[image]

[image]

How can I replace it with Total. I did try few codes but it didn't work out for me.
Thanks.

Comment: Its HTML is created server side and has no DOM id or class to target it with CSS. So the only options is overwriting it with JavaScript

Comment: Hi Danny, I tried using jQuery <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.ms-vb2 > nobr').each(function(){ console.log(this); var one = this; this.outerText = this.outerText.replace('Sum','Total '); });
    });
});
</script>      This code didn't work, but when I tried in browser console, it did work.

Comment: So the DOM isn't ready yet with SharePoint content when jQuery says the page is ready..

Comment: What should I do, any suggestions?

Comment: Use more advanced JS to only execute when the DOM is really ready